# Get value from JSON and display it (foreach command) in PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

Hello I've been trying to solve this by myself for a few hours now, with zero luck. I'm trying to use the foreach command in php to display a decoded value from json.

```
{
-car_data: {
car_id: "87",
car_cost: "62000",
```

So let's say I want to display the value of car_id, then below that the value of car_cost.
I need to do this using the foreach command. Please briefly explain the process. I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking...

If you have a JSON object and need to do something with it server side it is completely different to if you have a JSON object and want to do something with it on the webpage.

**N.B.**

Your JSON object is malformed there shouldn't be a `-` in the names.

### JSON Object

Made on the client side will look something like:

```
var cars = {car_data: {car_id: 87, car_cost: 62000}};
```

Alternatively, server side, you need to convert it to a PHP readable format:

```
$cars = json_decode('{"car_data":{"car_id":87,"car_cost":62000}}');
```

### JavaScript - Client Side

```
for(key in cars.car_data){
    console.log(key + " => " + cars.car_data[key]);
}
```

### PHP - Server Side

```
foreach($cars->car_data as $key => $value){
    echo "{$key} => {$value}\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);
foreach($decoded->cars_data as $car){
echo $car->car_cost;
}
```